# keyboardView padding not working from right

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, padding

Iam currently working on a custom keyboard, I added padding to my `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView` with value `android:padding="20dp"` but the padding not woking from right. Do I need to change the key width ?.
Here is the result [keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc7F1.jpg).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can achieve this using horizontalGap and verticalGap into keyboard xml file